# How to implement a full text search with spring-data-jpa with more than one search term

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa

I have an Entity with a text that I want to search with spring-data-jpa.
With one search-string this is easy:

```
@Repository
public interface PostRepository extends CrudRepository<Post, Long> {
    public List<Post> findByTextContainingIgnoreCase(String searchString);
}
```

But what happens when a user is searching for more than one term?
like 'book harry potter'

The only working solution I have so far is:

```
public List<Post> findByTextContainingIgnoreCaseAndTextContainingIgnoreCase(String term1, String term2);
```

That gets very annoying when you want to allow to search for a couple of terms.
I already tried to have an `Array<String>` or a `Collection<String>` as parameter but that is not working.

Anyone an idea how to solve that?

I am using spring-data-jpa with version 1.9.4.RELEASE